# Find Fourier transform of $\delta(e^{i\pi t}-i)$

Tags: fourier-transform

Find Fourier transform of $\delta(e^{i\pi t}-i)$
I used distribution $\langle\delta(t),\phi(t)\rangle=\phi(0)$ but it didn't work.

Comment: do you mean inverse fourier transform maybe ?

Comment: @AhmadBazzi i wrote wrong, it was edited

Comment: i have left you a detailed answer .. please check below.

Answer (score 1):

**Note: The OP was originally to find the inverse Fourier Transform of $\delta(e^{i\pi f}-i)$**

**Credits: Thanks @Skip for the comment below**

Notice that the argument is zero only when $e^{i \pi f} = i$, or in other words
\begin{equation}
\pi f = \frac{\pi}{2} + 2k \pi \qquad k \in \mathbb{Z}
\end{equation}
hence for $f = \frac{1}{2 } + 2k$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$, the Dirac function peaks at $1$, else it is $0$. This results in a "Dirac comb" or "train of impulses" as 
\begin{equation}
 \delta(e^{i\pi f}-i) = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} \delta(f - f_k)
\end{equation}
where $f_k = \frac{1}{2 } + 2k$. Applying inverse Fourier transforms on both sides, we have
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{F}^{-1}\delta(e^{i\pi f}-i) = \sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} \mathcal{F}^{-1}\delta(f - f_k) \tag{1}
\end{equation}

Using the Fourier transform table, we know that 
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{F}(e^{j 2 \pi f_0 t})
 =
 2 \pi \delta(f - f_0) 
\end{equation}
which means that
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{F}^{-1}(\delta(f - f_0)) = \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{j 2 \pi f_0 t}\tag{2}
\end{equation}
Using equation $(2)$ in $(1)$ we get
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{F}^{-1}\delta(e^{i\pi f}-i) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} e^{j 2 \pi f_k t}
\end{equation}
Replacing $f_k =\frac{1}{2 } + 2k$, we get
\begin{equation}
 \mathcal{F}^{-1}\delta(e^{i\pi f}-i) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty} e^{j 2 \pi (\frac{1}{2 } + 2k) t}
  = \frac{1}{2\pi}e^{j\pi t}\sum_{k = -\infty}^{\infty}   e^{4 k \pi t }
\end{equation}

Comment: I believe you meant $\pi f = \pi/2 + 2\pi k$.

Comment: yes you are right .. thanks for drawing my attention @Skip

Comment: nice solution @AhmadBazzi, but i want to find Fourier transform of $\delta(e^{i\pi t}-1)$

Comment: but you just edited right now @ThienHoangDang

Comment: sorry for wrong please bro @AhmadBazzi

Comment: you can consider asking another separate question @ThienHoangDang and reedit to your initial question for sake of clarity for other readers :)

Comment: @AhmadBazzi thanks for reminder :)

Comment: If $\delta(f(x))$ is defined as $\sum_{f(x_i) = 0} \delta(x - x_i)/|f'(x_i)|$, you need to divide by the derivatives. Not sure if the definition still makes sense when the derivative is not real, as for $\delta(e^{i \pi t} - 1)$. There's a typo in the last formula, $4 k \pi t$ should be multiplied by $j$. You can also write the result as a Dirac comb, since it's the Fourier transform of a comb.